# C# Draw Spiral Fill

Tags: c#, drawing, spiral

I have a question on Spiral Drawing.

The source below Referred from the link.
http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/2D-Graphics/Spiral.htm

Spiral gives you space.

I want the Spiral to fill the screen.

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pea)
{
  DoPage(pea.Graphics, ForeColor, ClientSize.Width,ClientSize.Height);
}

protected void DoPage(Graphics grfx, Color clr, int cx, int cy)
{
    const int iNumRevs = 3;
    int iNumPoints = iNumRevs * 2 * (cx + cy);
    PointF[] aptf = new PointF[iNumPoints];
    float fAngle, fScale;

    for (int i = 0; i < iNumPoints; i++)
    {
    fAngle = (float)(i * 2 * Math.PI / (iNumPoints / iNumRevs));
    fScale = 1 - (float)i / iNumPoints;

    aptf[i].X = (float)(cx / 2 * (1 + fScale * Math.Cos(fAngle)));
    aptf[i].Y = (float)(cy / 2 * (1 + fScale * Math.Sin(fAngle)));
    }
    grfx.DrawLines(new Pen(clr), aptf);
}
```

Image
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ijrjp.png

Comment: What about `FillPath` ?

Comment: Hi John. i do not know what you mean

Comment: There's a graphics method [`FillPath`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.fillpath(v=vs.110).aspx) (similar to how filling a path works in Photoshop). I'm not sure how easily you could define the path, but this might help you with the actual drawing once you have the path.

Comment: Thank you john. But what I want to do is draw the Spiral to fill the screen.

Comment: The first thing to do, is check you can draw anything. start simple, if you cant make a single line draw you cant make a spiral. if you can draw a single line, check to see if the points make sense. are they on the screen, ect ect ect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For sheer morbid curiosity, i created a new winforms application and pasted your code

This was my results

[image]

If this is not your desired results, please update your question to be more specific, include the picture, the desired results, and why its not working

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ijrjp.png
I do not know how to attach the screenshot and attached it as a link.

There are spaces above, below, and on the left as the program execution results.
I want the spiral to be drawn across the screen.

Comment: Is that so? Thank you for answer.

There was a confusion because it was a different spiral than what I saw.

Comment: @MrLee i mean my spiral is lopsided because of the form dimensions . however on a completely square form, a normal spiral will not touch all sides. this is what they do